# Check out files with TortoiseSVN from multiple repositories

Tags: version-control, tortoisesvn

I am trying to check out multiple items from two repositories.  One checkout goes to the root folder, and another would be checked out to a subdirectory.

Structure:

- root

  - source

    - invoice.p
  - compiled

    - invoice.r
  - forms

    - templates

      - invoice01.xml
      - invoice01.png

I right-click on the root folder and click "SVN Checkout...". I'm checking out the `invoice.p` and `invoice.r` files (specifically) with the same structure from the first repository.  The checkout type defaults to "Custom Depths" and everything goes fine.  The source and compiled folders show up with the check icon. Then I'm trying to get the invoice files from the second repository, but I am not sure how to check them out.  I can right-click on the `forms` folder in my checkout directory, but no matter how I set it up, it always pulls down the wrong structure, for example:

- forms

  - templates
  - forms

    - templates

      - invoice01.xml
      - invoice01.png

If I try to select the `root` folder to check out from the second repository, the original `source` and `compiled` folders get overwritten/deleted since they don't exist in the second repo. I can choose `invoice01.xml` and `invoice01.png` to go to the `templates` folder one at a time, but for some projects I may have 30-40 items I'd need to individually check out.  Is there an easier way to check out multiple items but to ignore the folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest working copies (which is what you're attempting to do here). The lone exception is if your inner working copy is created via an [`svn:external`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html) pointing elsewhere.

If you create an `svn:external` in the repository directory `root` is pointing at, call it `forms` and point it at the URL for the `forms` repository, you can do what you're attempting. Otherwise, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your query, in case the files are in the same root location like:

```
-forms
  -templates
   - invoice01.xml
   - invoice01.png
```

They shall be checked out with the Tortoise SVN URL Repository paths separated by * (asterisk symbol) like:

```
forms/templates/invoice01.xml*forms/templates/invoice01.png
```

Thus, in one go only, these files inside the root folder would be checked out even if the actual folder of templates had other files.

In case of a different root location, different folders have to be created and checked out. No other way!